# .NET 8 API in docker Container

Tags: docker, powershell

I'm trying to spin up a docker container with a powershell script.  The container is simple right now and just returns the string "Welcome to Azure Functions". The issue I'm having is with the Powershell script. The container is created and the api code is copied to the container. When I ping the container with postman I get an error

> Socket hang up

There are no errors in the logs of the container.

Here is the powershell script.

```
cd\
cd Code
cd mystuff
cd MITechCon
cd Code
cd fileupload.api

#Docker build -t mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 .

#Docker run -p 3629:80 -d mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0


# Pull the Azure Function image if it doesn't exist
if (-not (docker images -q mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0 2>$null)) {
    docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0
}


docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0

Write-Host "Waiting for things to catch up"
Start-Sleep $timeout

#--build, restore and deploy Doc Gen code ---------------------------+
Write-Host "Preparing code for file upload API container..."
dotnet restore "FileUpload.Api.csproj" 

dotnet build "FileUpload.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build 
dotnet publish "FileUpload.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false  

Write-Host "Waiting for things to catch up"
Start-Sleep $timeout


docker run -e AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:34808   -e AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true -p 34808:80  --name fileupload_API --hostname fileupload_API -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0 

cd\
cd app
cd publish

Write-Host "Copying code for document generator API container..."

#-- this next line copies the files to the container and usually fails the first time.  Simply, select it and re-run it.
docker cp . fileupload_API:/home/site/wwwroot
```

Here is the output from the docker container.

```
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Host.Triggers.Warmup[0]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       Initializing Warmup Extension.
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Host.Startup[503]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       Initializing Host. OperationId: '2c67011f-6db6-4cf5-89fe-e72292be7b20'.
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Host.Startup[504]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=2c67011f-6db6-4cf5-89fe-e72292be7b20
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       LoggerFilterOptions
2024-02-08 09:47:59       {
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "MinLevel": "None",
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "Rules": [
2024-02-08 09:47:59           {
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "ProviderName": null,
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "CategoryName": null,
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "LogLevel": null,
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
2024-02-08 09:47:59           },
2024-02-08 09:47:59           {
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "ProviderName": null,
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "CategoryName": "Host.Function.ToolingConsoleLog",
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "LogLevel": "Information",
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "Filter": null
2024-02-08 09:47:59           },
2024-02-08 09:47:59           {
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "CategoryName": null,
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "LogLevel": "None",
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "Filter": null
2024-02-08 09:47:59           },
2024-02-08 09:47:59           {
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "CategoryName": null,
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "LogLevel": null,
2024-02-08 09:47:59             "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
2024-02-08 09:47:59           }
2024-02-08 09:47:59         ]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       }
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       ConcurrencyOptions
2024-02-08 09:47:59       {
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "DynamicConcurrencyEnabled": false,
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "MaximumFunctionConcurrency": 500,
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "CPUThreshold": 0.8,
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "SnapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
2024-02-08 09:47:59       }
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
2024-02-08 09:47:59       {
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "BatchSize": 1000,
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "IsEnabled": true
2024-02-08 09:47:59       }
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       SingletonOptions
2024-02-08 09:47:59       {
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00",
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
2024-02-08 09:47:59       }
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       ScaleOptions
2024-02-08 09:47:59       {
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "ScaleMetricsMaxAge": "00:02:00",
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "ScaleMetricsSampleInterval": "00:00:10",
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "MetricsPurgeEnabled": true,
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "IsTargetScalingEnabled": true,
2024-02-08 09:47:59         "IsRuntimeScalingEnabled": false
2024-02-08 09:47:59       }
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.JobHostService[0]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       Starting JobHost
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Host.Startup[401]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       Starting Host (HostId=fileuploadapi-2137340777, InstanceId=1f2b1a6c-0be3-4692-96dd-607f9c655acc, Version=4.28.4.4, ProcessId=9, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=(null))
2024-02-08 09:47:59 info: Host.Startup[314]
2024-02-08 09:47:59       Loading functions metadata
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Host.Startup[326]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Reading functions metadata (Custom)
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Host.Startup[327]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       1 functions found (Custom)
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Host.Startup[315]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       1 functions loaded
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Host.Startup[0]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Generating 1 job function(s)
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher[0]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Worker process started and initialized.
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Host.Startup[0]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Found the following functions:
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Host.Functions.UploadFile
2024-02-08 09:48:00       
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.OptionsLoggingService[0]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       HttpOptions
2024-02-08 09:48:00       {
2024-02-08 09:48:00         "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
2024-02-08 09:48:00         "EnableChunkedRequestBinding": false,
2024-02-08 09:48:00         "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
2024-02-08 09:48:00         "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
2024-02-08 09:48:00         "RoutePrefix": "api"
2024-02-08 09:48:00       }
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostHttpRoutesManager[0]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Initializing function HTTP routes
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Mapped function route 'api/UploadFile' [get,post] to 'UploadFile'
2024-02-08 09:48:00       
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Host.Startup[412]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Host initialized (547ms)
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Host.Startup[413]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Host started (560ms)
2024-02-08 09:48:00 info: Host.Startup[0]
2024-02-08 09:48:00       Job host started
2024-02-08 09:48:00 Hosting environment: Production
2024-02-08 09:48:00 Content root path: /azure-functions-host
2024-02-08 09:48:00 Now listening on: http://[::]:34808
2024-02-08 09:48:00 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-02-08 09:48:04 info: Host.General[337]
2024-02-08 09:48:04       Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000D386290F'.
```

I would appreciate any help, Thanks!

Jim